# Unity3D 4 - imported animated fbx model interferes with physics

Tags: animation, import, unity-game-engine, physics, fbx

I have an imported model in .fbx format, with pre-baked animations. I want to apply physics to the model, however playing the animations seem to interfere with the physics

When the animations play the model won't 'fall'/collide but if I untick the 'Animation' in the inspector my model reacts correctly to the physics rigid body/mesh collider applied to the gameobject, but the minute I switch back on the animation the model moves back to it's original start position (but does play the animations correctly)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is the 'Animation' tick box I was talking about:

[image: Screenshot of inspector in unity showing Animation component]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by following [this advice](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/60382-SOLVED-Playing-animation-moves-gameobject-to-0-0) and making an empty game object to be used as a container, add the rigid body/mesh collider/scripts to the container game object, then add my model as a child of that game object. This way the transformations applied in script apply to the container, and the animations no longer affect the movement of the model!

Comment: if you are using the new animator then you can use the avatar masking and make sure the ground plane is red. this will keep the animations form moving the model

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar problem in Unity 5 where animations were affecting physics with a specific model I imported, but not others. It turns out I had to un-check "Apply root motion" on the Animator in question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure about this "Animation" checkbox you are referring to, but I have a couple hunches you can explore.

Unity's physics and collisions comes in a lot of flavors, and not all of them mix very well.  Rigidbody is good for anything that will have physics associated with it, but it comes with a TON of strings attached.  For example, Rigidbody's only collide with other Rigidbodys ([see bottom](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-CapsuleCollider.html)).  It sounds like you want to move your physics-thing around as a player or enemy or something.  RigidBodys are mixed when it comes to this.

The setting you need to play with is ".isKinematic" for the rigidbody component.  Turning this on turns off the physics simulation for rigidbodys, and the character controller or whatever will fall back as the default. Check out this script to toggle physics to so your character can push stuff around: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/17566/how-can-i-make-my-player-a-charactercontroller-pus.html

The other thing to keep in mind is that your model should not transform around the world *in animation*. Any transformations need to be handled by your game behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure what you meant that my model should not transform around the world in animation? It seems like there is some kind of physics forces or transformations baked into the animation itself, I have another model in my scene with animations that move 'on the spot' and i am able to make it translate/collide with physics no problem, it is only with this particular model I am experiencing strange behaviour. By the way I've updated my question with a screenshot of the Animation tick box i was talking about.

Comment: Seems like you got it figured out, but basically I meant movement actions should happen "in place", which is what it sounds like you are doing. Remember to mark your solution as such!